# py3dev outputs negative elevation values

Tags: python, gis, elevation

i just installed the py3dep module to work with topographic data but it keeps outputing negative values for any function that is supposed to retrieve elevation data, the py3dep version is '0.15.1' and the python version is  3.11.4

```
import py3dep
py3dep.elevation_bycoords([(9.1655608, 42.1695639)], crs="epsg:4326")
```

will output -999999.0 . Anybody ever faced something similar?